# Return a specific component from a matched grep string?

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression

HI supposed I want to extract only a component of a match, for example up to the first "_"

```
echo "Ha00030_Z6_L008_I1_001.fastq.gz" | grep -P -o '^H.+?_'
```

however the above returns, `Ha00030_`, but I only want `Ha00030`

is there something I can do, parenthesis or something to indicate to grep that I only want a certain component of the match?

edit: the ^H is not a requirement. so matching up to the first "_" is sufficient.

Comment: You're now getting answers that ignore the need to match on `H` at the start of the line since your 1 sample input string wouldn't require that - [edit] your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output, assuming you really do need to match on an initial `H` as your `grep` command implies.

Comment: If matching on a leading `H` is a requirement, what should happen if the string doesn't match? If these are filenames could you do, eg `for fn in H*fastq.gz`?

Comment: What should the output be if the input has no `_`s?

Comment: @EdMorton all inputs should have similar patterns that is will have "_" as delimiters; but its wise to think of contingencies however in this case its for  quick one off thing for a list of file names I need to extract

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Like this, using *exclude character class*:

```
$ echo "Ha00030_Z6_L008_I1_001.fastq.gz" | grep -Po '^[^_]+'
Ha00030
```

Or the same without `PCRE` aka `-P` that is not on all boxes at this time, like on latest `freeBSD` :

```
echo "Ha00030_Z6_L008_I1_001.fastq.gz" | grep -o '^[^_]\+'
```

The `[^_]+` means all but not a `_` with `+` quantifier

#### using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

**using *parameter expansion replacement***, see: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 and "Parameter Expansion" in `man bash`. Also see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

```
$ str=Ha00030_Z6_L008_I1_001.fastq.gz
$ echo "${str//_*/}"
Ha00030
```

or

```
$ IFS=_ read str _ <<< "Ha00030_Z6_L008_I1_001.fastq.gz"
$ echo "$str"
Ha00030
```

#### using `cut` (any shell)

`POSIX`ly

```
$ printf '%s\n' "Ha00030_Z6_L008_I1_001.fastq.gz" | cut -d'_' -f1
Ha00030
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on where you get your string from, you may be able to extract the field without leaving the shell:

```
a="Ha00030_Z6_L008_I1_001.fastq.gz"
echo "${a%%_*}"
```

Output

```
Ha00030
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider `awk`, especially if the logic could get more complex.

```
echo "Ha00030_Z6_L008_I1_001.fastq.gz" | awk -F_ '{print $1}'
```

`-F_` means to split on `_` and `{print $1}` prints the first of those.